# Load data from Database to richtextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

```
  using (SqlConnection myDatabaseConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString.ConnectionString))
            {
                myDatabaseConnection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Select [EmpID], [Name], [Address], [Birthday] from EmpTable where EmpID = @EmpID", myDatabaseConnection))
                SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", textBox1.Text);
                {
                using (SqlDataReader sqlreader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    if (sqlreader.Read())
                    {
                        textBox2.Text = sqlreader.GetInt32(sqlreader.GetOrdinal("EmpID")).ToString();                         
                        textBox3.Text = sqlreader.GetString(sqlreader.GetOrdinal("Name"));
                        textBox4.Text = sqlreader.GetString(sqlreader.GetOrdinal("Address"));
                        textBox5.Text = sqlreader.GetString(sqlreader.GetOrdinal("Birthday"));
                    }
                }
                }
            }
```

I have this to display a data from database to textBox.

[image]

How I can load the data from database into a richBox? something like this:

[image]

Where I can Highlight the data and copy the text.

Comment: Can you create a string from your dataset and write the string to a textbox control?  Something like `myTextBoxControl.Text = myStr;`

Comment: I know how load data to textBox. What I need is something like in the 2nd picture :)

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you're asking.  It looks like the data from your database is loaded into a formatted string and then loaded into a textbox control.  Are you asking how to highlight the text automatically?

Comment: Im asking how I will load data from database to richbox control something like in the picture above

Answer (score 2):

Use `String.Format`, like so:

```
    String template = 
@"EmpID\t\t{0}
Name\t\t{1}
Address\t\t{2}
Birthday\t\t{3}";

    using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection( config.ConnectionString ))
    {
        c.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select [EmpID], [Name], [Address], [Birthday] from EmpTable where EmpID = @EmpID", c))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", textBox1.Text);
            using (SqlDataReader rdr = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Int32  empId = rdr.GetInt32(rdr.GetOrdinal("EmpID")).ToString();                         
                    String name  = sqlreader.GetString(sqlreader.GetOrdinal("Name"));
                    String addr  = sqlreader.GetString(sqlreader.GetOrdinal("Address"));
                    String bday  = sqlreader.GetString(sqlreader.GetOrdinal("Birthday"));

                    textbox.Text = String.Format(template, empId, name, addr, bday);
                }//if
            }//using
        }//using
```

Comment: The OP seems to want the text separated into 2 columns, using `string.Format` with `\t` may not form columns correctly (some kind of zigzag instead).

Comment: There is also `String.PadLeft` and `String.PadRight` which can be used for this too.